# Getting friendly device names in python with windows

Tags: python, windows, guid

i want to get network interface name using device GUID.

i have a answer using `"ipconfig /all"` with parsing interface name

but `"ipconfig /all"` is very complex...

so i want to get like [Getting friendly device names in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551546/getting-friendly-device-names-in-python)

but this only show usb driver..

i can find the GUID(actually i exalty don't know) followed code:

```
import netifaces as ni
x=ni.interfaces()
print x
```

this show like this `['{CDC97813-CC28-4260-BA1E-F0CE3081DEC7}']`

i want to convert friendly device name like "local area connection"

Comment: sorry.. i'm confusing.. answer already exist in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913516/how-to-get-meaningful-network-interface-names-instead-of-guids-with-netifaces-un

Comment: Feel free to close as a duplicate if you think so. At the bottom of your question should be a little link that says 'close'; then, click on 'duplicate of' and enter the URL of the question you think this is a duplicate of.

Comment: yeah.. but this answer also right

Comment: It seems to be common practice here to close as duplicate anyway; I don't know the reasoning, but it's common enough that you should as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `ipconfig /all` which is quite complex indeed, consider these much simpler, as far as output goes, commands:

```
>netsh interface show interface

Admin State    State          Type             Interface Name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Enabled        Connected      Dedicated        Wireless Network Connection
Enabled        Disconnected   Dedicated        Local Area Connection
```

or

```
>netsh interface ip show interfaces

Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
 13          25        1500  connected     Wireless Network Connection
 12           5        1500  disconnected  Local Area Connection
```

These should be almost trivial to parse for an interface name

Comment: You can also use `wmic path Win32_NetworkAdapter where NetEnabled=True get /format:list`. The friendly name you want looks to be the `NetConnectionID` field. For the most reliable parsing I'd use the rawxml format. You can also use csv or just parse the list output. The `get` command can also take a comma-delimited list of fields to get instead of listing all fields. The GUID is one of the fields in case you want to filter on that in the `where` clause. See [`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216) on MSDN.