# How to detect if USB device is plugged in using python?

Tags: python, pyudev

I want to create a script that detects once the USB drive is plugged into the computer and for now just to print in the cmd **detect**.

Note I am using windows after my search I found that I need to use **pyudev package** in order to communicate with serial ports and I need to know the Vendor ID  of the USB device.

i tried to wrote the below code:

```py
import pyudev
context = pyudev.Context()
monitor = Monitor.from_netlink()
# For USB devices
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
# OR specifically for most USB serial devices
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='tty')
for action, device in monitor:
    vendor_id = device.get('ID_VENDOR_ID')

    if vendor_id in ['USB\\VID_0930&PID_6544&REV_0100'] or vendor_id in ['USB\\VID_0930&PID_6544']:
        print ('Detected {0} for device with vendor ID {1}'.format(action, vendor_id))
```

but the system crash and display this error :

```py
import fcntl ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fcntl'
```

**I think fcntl work only on Ubuntu**, because I tried to install the package but it didn't exist.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551546/getting-friendly-device-names-in-python

Comment: `if vendor_id in ['USB\\VID_0930&PID_6544&REV_0100'] or vendor_id in ['USB\\VID_0930&PID_6544']:` == `if vendor_id in ['USB\\VID_0930&PID_6544&REV_0100', 'USB\\VID_0930&PID_6544']:`

Answer (score 3):

i solved my question and i wrote this script that allow me to detect the last removable device that is plugged in.

code:

```
import win32api
import win32file

# Returns a list containing letters from removable drives
drive_list = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drive_list = drive_list.split("\x00")[0:-1]  # the last element is ""
for letter in drive_list:
    if win32file.GetDriveType(letter) == win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE:# check if the drive is of type removable 
print("list drives: {0}".format(letter))
```

Comment: final line (print) should be indented/part of if statement, no?

Answer (score 0):

try this one out

```
import win32file
def locate_usb():
    drive_list = []
    drivebits = win32file.GetLogicalDrives()
    for d in range(1, 26):
        mask = 1 << d
        if drivebits & mask:
            # here if the drive is at least there
            drname = '%c:\\' % chr(ord('A') + d)
            t = win32file.GetDriveType(drname)
            if t == win32file.DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
                drive_list.append(drname)
    return drive_list
```

code was actually taken from https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2006-December/005406.html

Answer (score 0):

I made a Python script that listens for specific devices and executes action when connected, eg:

```
pip install udev_monitor
udev_monitor.py --devices 0665:5161 --filters=usb --action /root/some_script.sh
```

You can find the full sources [here](https://github.com/netinvent/udev_monitor)

of course, using udev, this only works for Linux.